# Is there any good solution to profile a python module (which is a server)?

Tags: python, profiler, python-module

I've got some code organised this way:

```
main_dir/
 __init__.py (empty)
 common_file.py
 dir1/
  __init__.py (empty)
  (.py files)
 dir2/
  __init__.py (empty)
  (.py files, one of them is server.py)
```

To enable relative imports I run the server as a module:

```
python -m main_dir.dir2.server
```

I cannot profile the server with the "classic" cProfile way:

```
python -m cProfile -o <outputfilename> <script-name> <options>
```

cause cprofile doesn't have the -m option so doen't support running modules.

So how to to this?

Comment: `cProfile` has an [API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile), it is more than a command-line module.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it's a server. When I interrupt it with Ctrl+c, I also close interpreter so get no statistics.